# How to integrate captcha code joomla

Tags: php, joomla2.5, captcha

How do you integrate a captcha into a contact form in joomla 2.5?

Comment: You have no research work on this. This is strictly against the policies of Stackoverflow. If i could i would have voted you down. But nonetheless, providing you with the answer.

Comment: Voted down and voted for close, please read the FAQ before asking questions such as this one.

Comment: @praveen I search for above point but not get proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly enable the recaptcha plugin that comes with Joomla 2.5 (if you need captcha rather than recapture you will need to find a plugin for this [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/captcha)). Fill in the details in this plugin with the keys from the [recaptcha website](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). Then go to global configuration and select recatpcha in the Default Captcha option. Then it should display by default I believe.

Watch [this](http://people.joomla.org/videos/adeelch/video/859-how-to-setup-recaptcha-in-joomla-25-website.html) video for a step by step guide as well!

Comment: OK I don't understand that how to use public key and private key Thank's

Comment: No worries. The public and private keys are generated on the recaptcha site and you just copy and paste them into the parameters on the Joomla website - that's all you have to know for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the Joomla Extensions directory for Captcha.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/captcha

Comment: I want to configure a captcha plugins(default) which is install at joomla installation time

Answer (score -1):

Joomla supports **Extension**. To know what is an extension you can check this link. http://www.youjoomla.com/joomla-definitions-knowledgebase/what-is-a-joomla-extension.html

You can go to http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/captcha which is the extension directory for different versions of Joomla. you can pick the right one for you from there.

Comment: Well then you have to create your own. And why not use something that is already built and taken care of, probably in a better way than you can by writing your own? You also get community support for a plugin that is already there. Not for the one you create.

Comment: That is not what you asked for by your question. You are asking for something sort of tutorial which is out of the context of Stackoverflow. Read the FAQ.

Comment: By the way, each plugin comes with a Documentation that provides you with instructions on how to set it up. Please go through that.

Comment: Why i got a downvote here?

Comment: you dont explain properly, so please study joomla then explain